# Sub-Class Python datetime Object

Tags: python, datetime, inheritance

I am attempting to sub-class a datetime object to add more methods/utility functions:

```
   from datetime import datetime
   import pandas as pd
   from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay

   class DateTime(datetime):

      def __new__(cls, dt=None, **kwargs):
        if dt is None:
            cls._datetime = datetime.today()

        elif isinstance(dt, datetime):
            cls._datetime = dt

        else:
            cls._datetime = pd.to_datetime(dt, **kwargs)

        return datetime.__new__(cls, cls._datetime.year, cls._datetime.month, cls._datetime.day,
                                cls._datetime.hour, cls._datetime.minute, cls._datetime.second,
                                cls._datetime.microsecond, cls._datetime.tzinfo)

    def datetime(self):
        return self._datetime
```

I have a simple function which bumps the date by n business days and I create two variables; today and bumped:

```
   def date_add(start_date, days=5):
       return DateTime(start_date + BDay(days))

   today = DateTime()
   bumped = date_add(today, days=5)
```

Assuming today is the 22nd May 2020 and I print the two variables, I see the numbers I expect:

```
print(today)
print(bumped)

2020-05-22 00:48:00.760808
2020-05-29 00:48:00.760808
```

However, if I look at the datetime method, I see the value of the bumped item in both instances:

```
today.datetime()
Out[12]: DateTime(2020, 5, 29, 0, 48, 0, 760808)

bumped.datetime()
Out[13]: DateTime(2020, 5, 29, 0, 48, 0, 760808)
```

I appreciate what I am doing is wrong and I probably shouldn't attempt to subclass the datetime object anyway but what is wrong here?

Comment: That `cls._datetime` stuff doesn't make sense. Why are you storing that on the class? Why are you storing a whole separate `datetime` instance at all when your object *is* a datetime?

Comment: How would you initialize it with a datetime object?

Comment: I'd use a local variable instead of a class attribute (and I'd keep the `fold` value).

Comment: I see what you mean.  Not sure what you mean by fold.  Thanks Monica.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fold

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like:

```
import datetime

class DateTime:
    def __init__(self, some_datetime=None):
        if some_datetime is None:
            some_datetime = datetime.datetime.today()
        self._datetime = some_datetime

    def next_day(self):
        return DateTime(self._datetime + datetime.timedelta(1))

print(DateTime(datetime.datetime(1,2,3))._datetime)
print(DateTime(datetime.datetime(1,2,3)).next_day()._datetime)
```

However you might want to ask if it really makes sense to encapsulate the datetime like that. It would be much simpler to just do:

```
def next_day(some_datetime):
    return some_datetime + datetime.timedelta(1)
```